# Adding Conv Layer in front of pretrained model gives ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I want to combine a pretrained VGG16 model with a special input block, which is an input layer and a convolutional layer. The goal is to use a pre-trained RGB VGG16 imagenet model on grayscale images:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

img_height = 299
img_width = 299

def input_block(img_height = 299, img_width = 299):
    input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 1)
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name = 'grayscale_input_layer')
    x = Conv2D(3, (3,3),  padding= 'same', name = 'grayscale_RGB_layer')(img_input)
    return x

pretrained_model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor = input_block(img_height, img_width))
```

When I set the weight initalization of `VGG16()` to `'None'`, the model builds correctly, with the following desired structure:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
grayscale_input_layer (Input (None, 299, 299, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
grayscale_RGB_layer (Conv2D) (None, 299, 299, 3)       30        
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 299, 299, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 299, 299, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 149, 149, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 149, 149, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 149, 149, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 74, 74, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 74, 74, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 74, 74, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 74, 74, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 37, 37, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 18, 18, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 9, 9, 512)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,718
Trainable params: 14,714,718
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

However, when I set the weight initialization to `'imagenet'`,
I get the following error:

> ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 13 layers into a model with 14 layers.

This error makes sense, since I have added two layers in front of the VGG16 model instead of a single layer.

As a workaround, I have tried the following:

```
def input_block_model(img_height = 299, img_width = 299):
    input_shape = (img_height, img_width, 1)
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name = 'grayscale_input_layer')
    x = Conv2D(3, (3,3),  padding= 'same', name = 'grayscale_RGB_layer')(img_input)
    model = Model(img_input, x, name='input_block_model')
    return model

input_model = input_block_model(299,299)
pretrained_model = VGG16(weights = "imagenet", include_top=False)
combined_model = Model(input_model.input, 
pretrained_model(input_model.output))
print(combined_model.summary())
```

Then, the model structure is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
grayscale_input_layer (Input (None, 299, 299, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
grayscale_RGB_layer (Conv2D) (None, 299, 299, 3)       30        
_________________________________________________________________
vgg16 (Model)                multiple                  14714688  
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,718
Trainable params: 14,714,718
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The disadvantage of this structure, is that I cannot set properties of layers within the VGG16 model. I want to freeze certain layers for example in this model, which I cannot access via `combined_model.layers`. Does anyone have a working solution, such that I get the model structure as with the `'None'` initialization, but with pretrained ImageNet weights?

Comment: Of course you can access the layers of VGG16 model using `combined_model.layers[2].layers`.

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze or train layers using `combined_model.layers[2].layers` as mentioned in the comment above. You can may be simplify the model as follows:

```

```
img_input = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 1), name = 'grayscale_input_layer')
x = Conv2D(3, (3,3),  padding= 'same', name = 'grayscale_RGB_layer')(img_input)
x = VGG16(weights = None, include_top=False)(x)
model = Model(img_input, x)
model.summary()

for layer in model.layers[2].layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

```

Comment: can you say please why do we use (img_input) in front of our Conv2D? How is python syntax?